# TweetSharp StreamFilter Add Track Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, tweetsharp

I'm trying to write a C# app that collects tweets with a given hashtag. I'm using the tweetsharp library to help connect to the twitter API and I'm using the StreamFilter method. Can someone please help me figure out how to set the track parameter to search for a specific hashtag?

```
var service = new TwitterService(AppSettings.ConsumerKey, AppSettings.ConsumerSecret);
service.AuthenticateWith(AppSettings.AccessToken, AppSettings.AccessTokenSecret);

service.StreamFilter(StreamFilterHandler);

public void StreamFilterHandler(TwitterStreamArtifact artifact, TwitterResponse response)
    {
        var _response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Response);
    }
```